# Get all External Users of a SharePoint site using CSOM Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, pnp-powershell, external-users

i want all the external users of a SharePoint 2013 site using powershell CSOM or C# CSOM as we dont  have tenant admin rights to use Connect-SPOservice command. Is there any script in PnP or CSOM to get all external users. Please assist.

Comment: You've said you are dealing with SharePoint 2013, but then have tagged SPO and mentioned Connect-SPOservice. Please clarify if you're working with SPO or SharePoint server and remove the non-relevant tags/info.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it: get the SiteUsers collection, and then filter that by the presence of the string `#ext#` in the LoginName property of each user.

The below sample assumes you're pointing to your CSOM library

```
# organise session etc.
$siteURL = "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yourcollection/yoursite"
$username =  "your-username@yourtenant.sharepoint.com" 

$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)

# Create a client context connection
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials

# get the SiteUsers collection
$users = $ctx.Web.SiteUsers
$ctx.Load($users)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

foreach ($u in $users) 
{
    if ($u.LoginName.Contains('#ext#')) 
    {
        Write-host $u.LoginName
    }
}

$ctx.Dispose()
```

Other properties in the [user](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.user) object that are returned in this collection might also be of interest, such as `IsShareByEmailGuestUser`, depending on what you want to know.

Note that this gives you users in the *site collection*; depending on your permissions configuration not all of these users may have access to the site context.